# How do I close the Adobe Acrobat X welcome screen?

Tags: macos, adobe-acrobat

How do I close the welcome screen in Adobe Acrobat X (also Acrobat Pro X). It's very annoying to see this every time you start the program and have no document open.

Answer (score 5):

[Very first Google hit](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7feb.w.html#WS058ac72617541aaf704dfe7b12b22320c16-8000):

> Note: **In Mac OS, you can turn off the Welcome Screen** by setting a preference. Choose Acrobat/Reader > Preferences. In the Categories on the left, click General. In the Application Startup section, deselect Show Welcome Screen. **There is no similar option in Windows.**

Comment: This distinction actually makes sense: Windows has no concept of a running application without windows — that's why there are hacks using "minimize to systray" and similar behavior. *Something* needs to be displayed beyond a splash screen, and this is their way to design it. On OS X, it's slightly different due to the global menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the splash screen? You can disable it in Edit - Preferences - General
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have Reader version 10.1.1 to do this. 10.1 and earlier will not suffice.

Open the registry editor (RegEdit.exe), and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\FeatureLockDown\cWelcomeScreen
```

I had to create that last key (**cWelcomeScreen**). Right-click the **cWelcomeScreen** key, and select **New** | **DWORD value**. The new value appears in the right pane. Name it **bShowWelcomeScreen**. Leave the value set to zero (0).

Source: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/920/cpsid_92008.html